# Is it possible to load RDLX files from an SQL Server in ComponentOne ActiveReports?

Tags: silverlight, activereports, componentone

Is it possible to load RDLX files from an SQL Server in ComponentOne ActiveReports? I currently have the need to store the RDLX files in a third party service. I'm also using the webservice to render the reports becaus the viewer is in  SilverLight.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a Web Service that returns a dataset to use in ActiveReport Developer. Refer to the AR7 [documentation](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/arWLKDataSetWebService.html) link that will guide you in setting up Web Service that returns a dataset to use in ActiveReport Developer.

you can set up a Web Service that returns a report document which can be shown in a report viewer control.

AR7 also allows to set up a Web Service that returns a report document which can be shown in a report viewer control. The illustrated walkthrough can be found [here](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/arWLKDocumentWebService.html).

Regards,
Mohita